# How to create MO with OdooRPC, with the associated stock.pickings?

Tags: odoo, odoo-15

I'm currently working on programmatic creation of Manufacturing Orders (MOs) in Odoo 15. Although I've been successful in generating the MOs themselves, I've encountered a challenge where the associated stock pickings are not being created as expected. In contrast, when creating an MO manually through the front-end interface, the associated stock pickings are correctly attached. I've attempted to address this issue by utilizing the onchange method, but so far, I haven't achieved the desired outcome. I'm looking for guidance on how to resolve this issue and ensure that the appropriate stock pickings are generated and linked to the MOs when created programmatically

```
import odoorpc

def create_mo(product_id, product_qty, picking_type_id):
    # Define the connection parameters
    db = ''
    url = ''
    username = ''
    password = ''

    # Initialize the connection
    odoo = odoorpc.ODOO(url)

    # Authenticate
    odoo.login(db, username, password)

    # Get the picking type record
    picking_type = odoo.env['stock.picking.type'].browse(picking_type_id)

    # Access the mrp.bom model
    mrp_bom_model = odoo.env['mrp.bom']

    # Get the product template ID from the product ID
    product_template_id = odoo.env['product.product'].browse(product_id).product_tmpl_id.id

    # Define the search domain based on the product template ID
    search_domain = [('product_tmpl_id', '=', product_template_id)]

    # Search for the BOM record
    bom_ids = mrp_bom_model.search(search_domain)

    # Check if a BOM was found
    if bom_ids:
        # Retrieve the BOM record
        bom_record = mrp_bom_model.browse(bom_ids[0])

        # Access the mrp.production model to create the MO
        mrp_production_model = odoo.env['mrp.production']

        # Define the values for the new MO record
        values = {
            'product_id': product_id,
            'product_qty': product_qty,
            'bom_id': bom_record.id,
            'product_uom_id': bom_record.product_uom_id.id,
            'picking_type_id': picking_type.id,
            'location_src_id': 17,
            'location_dest_id': 18,
            
        }

        # Calculate the components from the BOM lines
        components = []
        for line in bom_record.bom_line_ids:
            components.append({
                'name': line.product_id.name,
                'product_id': line.product_id.id,
                'product_uom': line.product_uom_id.id,
                'product_uom_qty': line.product_qty * product_qty,
                'location_id': picking_type.default_location_src_id.id,
                'location_dest_id': picking_type.default_location_dest_id.id,
            })

        # Add the components to the MO values
        values['move_raw_ids'] = [(0, 0, line) for line in components]

        # Create the MO
        new_mo_id = mrp_production_model.create(values)

        # Confirm the MO
        mrp_production_model.button_plan([new_mo_id])


        # Browse the newly created MO
        new_mo = mrp_production_model.browse(new_mo_id)

        # Print the ID of the new MO
        print("New Manufacturing Order created with ID:", new_mo_id)
    else:
        print("No BOM found for the specified product.")

create_mo(6666,1,8)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone having the same issue, I end up just cloning an MO (with the picking type I wanted) and changing the product.id and bom to what I wanted. Not a clean solution but it worked.